# how to run the external-IP in a K8s namespace (installing JupyterHub)

Tags: kubernetes, jupyterhub

I am following the instructions here:
https://z2jh.jupyter.org/en/stable/jupyterhub/installation.html

to install locally with kubernetes and minikube a jupyter hub.

Its almost done as can be seen in the pic
[image]

the namespace is called k8s-namespace-jose

I had to run the command:
kubectl --namespace  get service proxy-public --output jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[].ip}'

In order to get the EXTERNAL-IP shown above.

The thing is that going to:
http://104.196.41.97   does not work (server not responding)

nor the folowing works:
http://104.196.41.97:80

the error that I get is:
[image]
What can I do in order to get my jupyterhub in my local server?

EDIT:
In order to have all the info about the loadbalancer:

```
Name:                     proxy-public
Namespace:                k8s-namespace-jose
Labels:                   app=jupyterhub
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Helm
                          chart=jupyterhub-2.0.0
                          component=proxy-public
                          heritage=Helm
                          release=helm-release-name-jose
Annotations:              meta.helm.sh/release-name: helm-release-name-jose
                          meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: k8s-namespace-jose
Selector:                 component=proxy,release=helm-release-name-jose
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.103.131.233
IPs:                      10.103.131.233
External IPs:             104.196.41.97
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               http/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32297/TCP
Endpoints:                10.244.0.13:8000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the minikube installation, **probably the address is the address of minikube cluster** and not the External-IP

Can you try an alternative to **hit the minikube IP instead of the External IP**?

```
sgrigori@sgrigori-vbox:~/Dev/jupyterhub$ minikube ip
192.168.49.2
```

and use your node port 32297

http://192.168.49.2:32297

Comment: Probably there is something configured on your loadbalancer that breaks it. I used
minikube tunnel 
on another window and on another window I get with 
kubectl --namespace k8s-namespace-spiros get service proxy-public
the same IP for CLUSTER-IP and EXTERNAL-IP and hitting `http://EXTERNAL-IP` I get response

Comment: still the same safari answer :-( I added some info in the question about loadBalancer